# 3D surface plot from external data with no header

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to figure out how I can draw my 3D surface plot using pgfplots when external data is scattered to an excel file in 2D with no headers. I wasted almost 2 days now and have no clue how can I achieve this.

The visualization of the data with 3D surface plot in LABVIEW is given below. I also added how the excel file looks like and gave tab delimited txt file below.

Thanks in advance.

[Tab delimited .txt of data is here](https://pastebin.com/bcwBzbcG)
[image: LABVIEW Surface Plot]
[image: How the data looks]

Comment: As a first step, use pgfplotstable to read and print out the data.  If that works, plotting it should be no problem.

Comment: You need to tell pgfplots how your data is organized. From first principles, the program does not know whether data is given as (x, y, z) coordinates, array of z coordinates on an x-y grid… Look at the pgfplots manual and try to come up with a minimal working example. We can help you from thereon.